# MongoDB log rotation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I configure systemLog in `mongod.conf` as

```
systemLog:    
  destination: file    
  logAppend: true  
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

The. Log file size grow day by day even peimary server shift from one to another in replica set.

Can we make logAppend as false?
Is it create trouble? while recovering data if new server added in replica set or any failure happenes in existing server in same replica set.

Answer (score 0):

enter command

```
db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```